# Regex to replace all unless end of line ( $ in [ ] issue )

Tags: python, regex

Let's say I have a string:

```
s = "4n5n6n"
```

I would like to create a regex that removes everything except numbers and the `n` at the end of a string. So the final solution should look like this:

```
s = "456n"
```

If I use a regex like so:

```
re.sub(r'[^n$\d]', "", s)
```

The `$` seems to lose its meaning when inside the brackets. What is the solution to this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
re.sub(r'[^n\d]|n(?!$)', "", s)
```

[regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/uK5lK7)

This will match any non-digit and any character other than `n`, or any `n` which is not at the end (the "not at the end" being expressed by the negative lookahead `(?! ... )` with a `$` inside.

Answer (score 1):

Another way, maybe more simple to read than the @Jerry solution (which is still perfect) is to replace any `n` character followed by a number by the number catched:

```
>>> re.sub(r'n(\d+)', "\g<1>", s)
'456n'
```